# How to add ajax modal in rails 4 and bootstrap 3 with devise?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, devise, omniauth

I need to create a modal for login and register form in a website

as I can do to get the result of image below?

[Modal login example from airbnb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmiLH.jpg)

I have Rails 4, bootstrap 3, Devise and Omniauth (for facebook login)

Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: The documetation is a good place to start:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I have no problems in bootstrap, I know how to occupy the framework, but I do not know connect devise forms with bootstrap modal

Comment: Okay. I don't use Devise, so I can't help much. Hopefully someone who is familiar with it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your willingness